# Distribution of a quadratic function involving a random gaussian matrix

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-matrices

Assume $A$ is a gaussian matrix of size $n \times N$ where $n\ll N$. All the entries of $A$ are independent and identically distributed
normal $\mathcal N(0, 1/n)$.

Moreover, assume that $x$ is a vector of size $N$.

Denote $H=A^{*}A-I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Can someone help me understand the distribution of $Hx$?

In a [research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.3574.pdf) I read (pg 3, section D), they state that $Hx$ behaves as a kind of noisy random vector and is accurately modeled as a vector with i.i.d. Gaussian entries with
variance $ \frac{1}{n} \|x\|^{2}$

Can someone help me prove it?

I also have a follow-up question:

**What can I say about distribution of  $Hx$, if all entries of  $A$ were independent and identically distributed $\operatorname{Bern}(p)$ variables.**
.

Comment: Have you read the papers by Donoho referenced in the paper that you linked to?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, No. I haven't read the other papers.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, I just checked ref [12], but it does not have what I am looking for.

Comment: References 4, 5, 6, and 7 are where this was done for the normal case.  There's a large research literature on random matrices, but these kinds of results are extremely technical- there may be results for the bern(p) case, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: You've asked two separate questions here (1) how can this behavior be established for random matrices with normal entries and (2) what happens when the entries are Bernoulli rather than normal.  It would help if you narrowed your question down to one or the other.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, I was thinking since the paper is mentioning it like "an obvious" result, maybe it is not technical. So I am guessing that is not the case?

Comment: No, these are very advanced results.

Comment: @BrianBorchers , I am more interested in the Bernoulli case than the gaussian case. For the  Bern case, I am thinking A*A  will have each entry again bern. with parameter equal to 1- n(1-1/p^2).